# iOS app not updating even after updating from App Store

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, app-store

I built an iOS app, version number `1.0`, and I submitted this app to the App Store.

Now my clients install this application from App Store and later on they complained about the bugs and crash issues.

I fixed the bugs and crash issues in version `1.0` and again I submitted the new version `2.0`.

But when my clients update the app to version `2.0` they notice the same issues and bugs, **unless they uninstall the app and reinstall from App Store**.

Why is the iOS app not actually updating after updating from App Store?

Comment: What kind of bugs and crashes are we talking about? Are they related to persisted data? This would explain why they're fixed with a clean install

Comment: Bugs was the userdefaults not storing well and crash was wrong logic code (if/else condition)

Comment: @MohammedNabil Hi man, if you don't post the code we can't help you... For storing some information and data you must use Core Data Framework. But it's a supposition because we don't see you code... Another question: why you call the second version 2.0 and not 1.1 ? Have a nice day

Comment: @Fabio Regarding the version i just give you an example i also tried this my doing 2.0 to 2.1 and so on

Comment: @MohammedNabil To me this is clearly a migration bug. You've implemented a certain functionality in version 1.0 that persisted data in the userDefaults. But something was wrong with the implementation so it crashed. In 2.0 you fixed the implementation but only for those who start with version 2.0. The users on version 1.0 still run into this crash because their persisted data still relies on the functionality of version 1.0. When deleting the app all data in the userDefaults gets erased automatically. This is the reason why a reinstall fixes the problem

Comment: @ProtocolGuy So how can i fix the migration bug ?

Comment: @MohammedNabil Well, there are so many solutions on how to achieve this. Basically every time you change code that is related to persisted data, you have to make sure that older versions still work. I'd suggest reading some docs / articles about "migration" in general. It's hard to give you a concrete answer, especially without knowing your code.